# PGPoolingDataSource does not honor default autocommit

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling

It is documented to use datasource with getConnection function
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/ds-ds.html

When datasource has autocommit disabled, we have

```
ds.isDefaultAutoCommit
```

res0: Boolean = false

Getting connection:

```
val conn = ds.getConnection
```

Autocommit is enabled:

```
conn.getAutoCommit
```

res1: Boolean = true

Looking at the code we see that getConnection uses parent class function without changing commit mode
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.java

Is that just implementation anomaly/limitation or there is some other reasoning behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug. The class `PGPooledConnection` (the handle to the connection in the pool) takes a boolean argument `autoCommit` in its constructor, but it doesn't do anything with it (like resetting the auto commit status before handing out the logical connection).

You should create an issue on their github.